# command line API for decompiling dll file

Tags: dll, decompiling

I want to read dll contents from command line api So I can access it at run time.

Is there any tool that has a CLI API for de-compiling code?

Comment: This is far too vague. Are you looking to get the entire contents of the DLL spit out? Also "command line API" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Walker has a console mode. It of course doesn't decompile, but that is most likely not what you need anyway. (That's not needed to access a DLL)